# What does the phrase 'but that' mean?

Tags: grammar

What does the phrase 'but that' mean? 
e.g., in On Walden Pond.
'why has man rooted himself thus firmly in the earth, but that he may rise in the same proportion into the heavens above? '

Comment: It means "except that" or, possibly, "except when" he may rise.

Comment: Strangely, the meaning of "except that" doesn't seem to help the sentence make more sense. To me, it feels more like the author was poetically reaching for "hoping that" or "expecting that".

Comment: @Ian: "Except [in the case] that ..." Use *where* or *when* in place of *that* if it suits you. These all mean the same thing in context.

Comment: "but that" here means "unless it were not that he may rise"

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295137

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rhetorical flourish. You can substitute "if not" for "but", and read in a "so" in front of the "that":

> Why has man rooted himself thus firmly in the earth, **if not (so) that** he may rise in the same proportion into the heavens above?

Because it is in the form of a rhetorical question, we can interpret this as something like

> What explanation can there be [for man rooting himself etc.], if the explanation is not so that [he may rise etc.]? Well, obviously, there isn't any other explanation!

This use of "but" to mean "if not" may be familiar to you from the phrase [*there **but for** the grace of God (go I)*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/there-but-for-the-grace-of-god-go-i). The rhetorical structure may also be familiar if we strip it down:

> Why X, if not because of Y?

[Jane Austen's 1813 *Pride and Prejudice*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-h/1342-h.htm#link2HCH0057) (via Project Gutenberg) contains a famous example at the end of Chapter 57, also using "but" in place of "if not":

> For what do we live, **but** to make sport for our neighbours, and laugh at them in our turn?

Another example, from a nineteenth century sermon on the Lord's prayer:

> For what is it we pray for, **but that** we may commit no evil, for which we should be separated from that holy Bread.
>   —[*A Select Library of the Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers of the Christian Church*, 1888, Philip Schaff, Ed.](https://books.google.com/books?id=hwYNAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22but%20that%20we%20may%22&pg=PA289#v=onepage&q=%22but%20that%20we%20may%22&f=false)

And some more recent examples of the structure, using more modern language:

> Why do concepts, inferences, etc. of subjects age 2 to 6 remain preoperational, if not because of illegitimate intrusions of causality and an insufficient Causality?
>   —Jean Piaget, 1974, quoted in [Webster Callaway's *Jean Piaget: A Most Outrageous Deception*, 2001](https://books.google.com/books?id=j3bTqBYYtBYC&lpg=PA64&dq=why%20%22if%20not%20because%22&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q=why%20%22if%20not%20because%22&f=false)
>
> And why is asbestos treated less favorably, if not because it is foreign? Plainly, because it is dangerous.
>   —[*Trade and Human Health and Safety*, 2006, George Bermann & Petros Mavroidis, Ed.](https://books.google.com/books?id=2k2BRseO1GsC&lpg=PA214&dq=why%20%22if%20not%20because%22&pg=PA214#v=onepage&q=why%20%22if%20not%20because%22&f=false) (Note that in this case the authors have *answered* the rhetorical question with "because Z".)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty obscure usage, but in in this context, everything after the "but" is an answer to the "why" in the first clause.  "Why is man rooted?  The answer is so he may rise."

Comment: More accurately: the **only** answer is ...

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it means "unless."

Answer (score -1):

In this case, "but that" make a opposite connector with the first sentence and last one, like a possibility, even if **firmly in the earth**, he isn't prevented and might of **rise in the same proportion into the heavens above**.

Comment: Even it -> even if?

Comment: Your example sentence is nonsense.